# C++ Pattern to replace runtime type selection for GUI generator

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm creating a *GUI Generator* for some data that is created from `Node` classes. Each `Node` subclass represents a different type of data (e.g. StringNode, IntNode).

At runtime, I don't know the derived types of the nodes. I feel like my only solution is to have a massive list of `if` statements:

```
if (auto stringNode = dynamic_cast<StringNode*>(node)) {
    /* Generate text input */
} else if (auto intNode = dynamic_cast<IntNode*>(node)) {
    /* Generate spin box */
} 
// etc...
```

This seems inefficient and requires careful ordering so derived types are above types they inherit.

Is there another way to do this that uses polymorphism?

- The *GUI Generator* is not in the library where `Node` is defined.
  The GUI for each node may be unique to the derived type (e.g. date picker).
- I can't add a virtual `generateGui()` method on the nodes as this would require generating GUI in the library.
- I can edit the `Node` class.
- `Node` subclasses can be added outside this library and should also allow for their GUI to be generated.
- I've looked at [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but I don't think they will fit as not all classes or GUI generators will be available in the library.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer this implementation:

```
enum class NodeType { Unknown, String, Int, Float };
using CreateFunc = void(*)(Node *node);
using TypeFunc = bool(*)(Node *node);

// define type-checkers:
bool IsStringNode(Node *node)
{
    return dynamic_cast<StringNode*>(node) != nullptr;
}
bool IsIntNode(Node *node)
{
    return dynamic_cast<IntNode*>(node) != nullptr;
}
bool IsFloatNode(Node *node)
{
    return dynamic_cast<FloatNode*>(node) != nullptr;
}


class GuiGenerator
{
public:
// define specific creators:
    static void CreateStringGui(Node *node) { cout << "Creating String Gui" << endl; }
    static void CreateIntGui(Node *node)  { cout << "Creating Int Gui" << endl; }
    static void CreateFloatGui(Node *node)  { cout << "Creating Float Gui" << endl; }
    //void Create(<Some other node>) {}
};

map<NodeType, CreateFunc> Creators =
{
    { NodeType::String, &GuiGenerator::CreateStringGui },
    { NodeType::Int, &GuiGenerator::CreateIntGui },
    { NodeType::Float, &GuiGenerator::CreateFloatGui }
};

NodeType GetType(Node *node)
{
    vector<pair<NodeType, TypeFunc>> types =
    {
        { NodeType::String, &IsStringNode },
        { NodeType::Int, &IsIntNode },
        { NodeType::Float, &IsFloatNode }
    };

    for(auto &a : types)
        if(a.second(node))
            return a.first;
    return NodeType::Unknown;
}

// And here is it: your simplified function
//
static void CreateGUI(Node *node)
{
    auto type = GetType(node);
    Creators[type](node);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Node *node1 = new StringNode();
Node *node2 = new IntNode();
Node *node3 = new FloatNode();

CreateGUI(node1);
CreateGUI(node2);
CreateGUI(node3);
```

There are no error handling provided for simplification.